# XSLT Template to avoid certain mode

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT which include many module XSLT. Each sub-XSLT has a different mode to process. In main XSLT there is a identity template like this

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="#all" priority="-1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

but when we apply this to conversion we found that some mode that doesn't need identical conversion, is convert through this, So we modified this as below and it run perfectly:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="mode1 mode2 mode3 mode4 mode7 mode8" priority="-1">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

As I know that `mode5` and `mode6` doesn't need identity conversion and need to avoid it in conversion. But with above procedure we have to edit this template each time when we add new mode.

Is there any other process, in which we apply identity template to mode `#all` and avoid only `mode5` and `mode6`, to avoid future development conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to define e.g. `mode="#all except (mode5,  mode6)"` so I am afraid the answer is no, you will have to do some editing.

Answer (score 1):

The XSLT 3.0 way of doing this is to declare the modes with their default action:

```
<xsl:mode name="mode1" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:mode name="mode2" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:mode name="mode3" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:mode name="mode4" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:mode name="mode7" on-no-match="deep-skip"/>
<xsl:mode name="mode8" on-no-match="fail"/>
```

and when you have one mode per module, as you appear to, you would typically put the mode declaration in the module.

That probably won't help you directly. But having used the one-mode-per-module approach, I would be inclined to replicate the default template rule in each module where it applies, for one mode only, rather than using lists of modes or `mode="#all"`.